# Convert factor levels into lists for use in dynamic input in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to convert factor levels output into a list so I can create a dynamic input for a SelectInput function in R Shiny.

Basically, I import a CSV file, and would like to create the drop-down list in SelectInput by using the "categories" (levels) in the first column of the CSV file.

So, in UI.R I have:

```
uiOutput("categoryPicker")
```

And in server.R I have:

```
datatwo <- read.csv(file="data2.csv",head=TRUE,sep=",")
```

then, in the "shinyServer(function(input, output)" section ("category" is a header in the CSV file, by the way):

```
output$categoryPicker <- reactiveUI(function() {
categories <- levels(datatwo$category)
selectInput("category", "Category:", categories)
})
```

This doesn't work, gives me the following error:

> Error in choices[[choiceName]] : subscript out of bounds

The str(categories) output is as follows:

> chr [1:22] "" "Cat1" "Cat2" "Cat3" "Cat4" "Cat5" ...

If I do "list(levels(datatwo$category)", it just gives me one drop down, which is the entire str(categories) output:

> List of 1
>   $ : chr [1:22] "" "Cat1" "Cat2" "Cat3" ...

I'm trying to get this in the form of (such that when str(x) is done the output would be):

> List of X 
>   $ Cat1: chr "Cat1" 
>   $ Cat2: chr "Cat2" 
>   $ Cat3: chr "Cat3" 
>   ...

But I'm not sure how to do this.  I'm also not sure why the first item is a "" [empty string].  I'm pretty new to R and Shiny so forgive my ignorance, but any help would be greatly appreciated.

BTW, I've been working off this tutorial:
http://rstudio.github.com/shiny/tutorial/#dynamic-ui

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example instead of code snippets.

Comment: first guess, maybe you need to use `as.list` on `categories`, instead of `list`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if the names in the list are important or not, but this should give you what you want:

```
setNames(as.list(categories), categories)
```